# type conversion in go

Tags: go, type-conversion

I am very new to go and I'm having problems with accessing data of structures that are not known at runtime:

```
type Nested struct {
  Value string
}

type TypeA struct {
  Nested
  Foo string
}

type TypeB struct {
  Nested
  Bar string
}
```

I have to implement the following callback:

```
func Callback(param interface{}) {

}
```

`param` can be `*TypeA` or `*TypeB`.

How can I cast type-convert/cast `param`, so that I can access the known `Nested` element common to both types?

Because interfaces are implemented implicitly I thought I could do something like this

```
type Whatever struct {
  Nested
}
```

and then

```
func Callback(param interface{}) {
  nst := param.(*Whatever)
  fmt.Printf(nst.Nested.Value)
}
```

however this results in

`interface {} is *misc.TypeA, not *misc.Whatever`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dynamic value in `param` is of type `*misc.TypeA`, you can only [type assert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) `*misc.TypeA`.

So do that, then you can access the `Nested` field:

```
func Callback(param interface{}) {
    nst := param.(*TypeA)
    fmt.Printf(nst.Nested.Value)
}
```

If it can be a value of more types, use a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements):

```
func Callback(param interface{}) {
    switch nst := param.(type) {
    case *TypeA:
        fmt.Println(nst.Nested.Value)
    case *TypeB:
        fmt.Println(nst.Nested.Value)
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
a := &TypeA{
    Nested: Nested{Value: "val"},
}
Callback(a)
b := &TypeB{
    Nested: Nested{Value: "val"},
}
Callback(b)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/e0Qwj7lSrJZ)):

```
val
val
```

If you intend to do the same in all cases, you may reduce the code like this:

```
func Callback(param interface{}) {
    var nst Nested
    switch x := param.(type) {
    case *TypeA:
        nst = x.Nested
    case *TypeB:
        nst = x.Nested
    }
    fmt.Println(nst.Value)
}
```

This will output the same. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-_6FVI5_vuS).

Of course the best thing would be to use interfaces. Use an interface with a `GetNested() Nested` method, and have your types implement it. And change `Callback()` to accept a value of this interface type. And since you're already using embedding (`Nested` into `TypeA` and `TypeB`), it's convenient to implement this `GetNested()` function once, on `Nested` itself:

```
func (n Nested) GetNested() Nested {
    return n
}

type HasNested interface {
    GetNested() Nested
}

func Callback(nst HasNested) {
    fmt.Println(nst.GetNested().Value)
}
```

And that's all. This will again output the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/x1nj_-SMdIO).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @icza. the problem is, both the callback and the types are from a library I am using, not my own code. so I have to live with what it is.

Comment: @gofrm Then the above presented type switch is the most convenient for you.